# Applying search filter in your html table

Tags: php, html

I have a table which has millions of records in it and I want to apply search filter for ContactOwner or any other relevant field.I am not able to implement the desired requirement.Please check the code and help to resolve it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
           <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
background-position: 10px 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

 #example {
 border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
 }

  #example th, #example td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  }

  #example tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  #example tr.header, #example tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

   <h2>My Customers</h2>

 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <table id="example">
  <tr class="header">
            <th>id</th>
            <th>ContactOwner</th>
            <th>LeadSource</th>
            <th>First_name</th>
            <th>Last_name</th>
            <th>AccountName</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>EmailID</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Industry</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Assistant</th>
            <th>AsstPhone</th>
            <th>ReportsTo</th>
            <th>LinkedIn</th>
            <th>CallStatus</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>OtherStreet</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Description</th>
  </tr>

 </table>
  <?php         
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ContactOwner'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['LeadSource'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['First_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Last_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['AccountName'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['EmailID'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Department'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Industry'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Phone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Mobile'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Fax'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['DOB'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Assistant'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['AsstPhone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ReportsTo'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['LinkedIn'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['CallStatus'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Street'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['OtherStreet'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['City'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['State'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Zip'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Country'].'</td>    
                <td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>            
            </tr>';

            ?>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable();
} );

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js">

</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i would suggest you to use `jquery datatable` plugin to use searching for table records

Comment: Search either client side or server side ?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan: Okay Mahesh.But is it easy to implement it.As I tried it earlier,but it was not working.Well,I will try it again and if I get any issue,I will ask again.

Comment: @JasL yes it is, let me know if you having any issue to implement dataTable.

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan: I tried using DataTable, same error is appearing.I have updated the code.So please check if possible for you and let me know

Comment: @JasL I have updated your question and added to answer as well, you can mark my answer as useful with `dataTable` plugin demo

Comment: @JasL StackOverflow is here to help you with specific problems you're facing, not doing whole job for you

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan: The code you shared is working but with dummy data.I have many records,how can I achieve the same result with those records?

Comment: @JasL it will work with many records too, you need to loop your data inside `tbody` with each `tr` and plugin with work. Do not forget to copy my answer code properly

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan : sure, I copied it but I have million of records and I think it will not be possible to do that.

Comment: @JasL datatables have server side option, so you can use that with pagination, maheshchhouhan@gmail.com this is my email id, mail me for further communications :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **dataTable** plugin to search table records

**Try this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```css
<style>

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
background-position: 10px 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

 #example {
 border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
 }

  #example th, #example td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  }

  #example tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  #example tr.header, #example tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">





  </head>

  <body>

   <h2>My Customers</h2>

 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
  <tr class="header">
        <th>id</th>
        <th>ContactOwner</th>
        <th>LeadSource</th>
        <th>First_name</th>
        <th>Last_name</th>
        <th>AccountName</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>EmailID</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Industry</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Assistant</th>
        <th>AsstPhone</th>
        <th>ReportsTo</th>
        <th>LinkedIn</th>
        <th>CallStatus</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>OtherStreet</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>id</td>
        <td>ContactOwner</td>
        <td>LeadSource</td>
        <td>First_name</td>
        <td>Last_name</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>EmailID</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Fax</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Assistant</td>
        <td>AsstPhone</td>
        <td>ReportsTo</td>
        <td>LinkedIn</td>
        <td>CallStatus</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>OtherStreet</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>id</td>
        <td>ContactOwner</td>
        <td>LeadSource</td>
        <td>First_name</td>
        <td>Last_name</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>EmailID</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Fax</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Assistant</td>
        <td>AsstPhone</td>
        <td>ReportsTo</td>
        <td>LinkedIn</td>
        <td>CallStatus</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>OtherStreet</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>id</td>
        <td>ContactOwner</td>
        <td>LeadSource</td>
        <td>First_name</td>
        <td>Last_name</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>EmailID</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Fax</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Assistant</td>
        <td>AsstPhone</td>
        <td>ReportsTo</td>
        <td>LinkedIn</td>
        <td>CallStatus</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>OtherStreet</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>id</td>
        <td>ContactOwner</td>
        <td>LeadSource</td>
        <td>First_name</td>
        <td>Last_name</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>EmailID</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Fax</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Assistant</td>
        <td>AsstPhone</td>
        <td>ReportsTo</td>
        <td>LinkedIn</td>
        <td>CallStatus</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>OtherStreet</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>id</td>
        <td>ContactOwner</td>
        <td>LeadSource</td>
        <td>First_name</td>
        <td>Last_name</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>EmailID</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Fax</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Assistant</td>
        <td>AsstPhone</td>
        <td>ReportsTo</td>
        <td>LinkedIn</td>
        <td>CallStatus</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>OtherStreet</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>id</td>
        <td>ContactOwner</td>
        <td>LeadSource</td>
        <td>First_name</td>
        <td>Last_name</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>EmailID</td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td>Industry</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Mobile</td>
        <td>Fax</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Assistant</td>
        <td>AsstPhone</td>
        <td>ReportsTo</td>
        <td>LinkedIn</td>
        <td>CallStatus</td>
        <td>Street</td>
        <td>OtherStreet</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>Description</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>      
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to achieve is use dataTable library of JQuery. 
Please follow below link
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

```
$("#example").dataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks ,I will try to implement it.